# Why doesn't this work for Rudin Exercise 3.8

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The problem is 3.8 exercise in baby Rudin:

> If $ \sum{a_n} $ converges and $\{b_n\}$ is bounded and monotonic, prove that $\sum{a_nb_n}$ converges.

Why can't I just do this?:

Let $M$ be an upper bound of $\{b_n\}$. Choose $N$ such that for all $n,m\ge N$,
$$ \sum_{k=n}^m{a_k} \le {\epsilon \over  M}$$

Then, $$\sum_{k=n}^m{a_kb_k} \le M\sum_{k=n}^m{a_k} \le \epsilon $$

If someone has a quickish clear proof for this, I'd love to see it also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is a Cauchy Product, just a normal term by term one so
$\sum_{n=1}^m{a_nb_n} = a_1b_1+a_2b_2.....$ right?

Comment: *Why can't I just do this?* Well, for one thing, this inequality doesn't follow:    $\sum_{k=n}^m{a_kb_k} \le M\sum_{k=n}^m{a_k}$.

Comment: But $b_k$ is less than M for all k? Whats the problem with it? each term is less than M so just factor out M?

Comment: Try to prove it and you should discover the flaw in your proof...

Comment: The above was my attempt to prove it, is perhaps the problem with absolute values?

Comment: You definitely need absolute values.

Comment: Nevermind, turns out this was right, I just had to add the absolute value bars, but that doesn't really change anything else. See this solutions manuel - https://www.scribd.com/doc/76236535/53/Exercise-3-3

Comment: It's unusual to give monotonicity as an unnecessary assumption. Could there be a problem with $b_n$ potentially alternating positive and negative in such a way to cause $\sum a_nb_n$ to diverge? See @robjohn's solution below. So I think there is an error in the solution as given and in the document linked. You might be able to salvage it by noting that $b_n$ is eventually only positive or negative. I tried to fix the solution, but could not do so quickly without using the fact that $b_n$ converges.

Answer (score 11):

**Need to Use Monotonicity**

Since you did not use the monotonicity of $b_n$, you would need to know that the sum converges absolutely to make your argument work. Take for example
$$
a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n
$$
and
$$
b_n=1+(-1)^{n-1}
$$
The sum of $a_n$ is a well known convergent series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n=\log(2)
$$
However, since $b_n=0$ for even $n$ and $b_n=2$ for odd $n$, we have that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{2n-1}
$$
which diverges by comparison to the Harmonic series.

---

**Using Monotonicity**

Since $b_n$ is bounded and monotonic, let $b_\infty=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n$. Furthermore, since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, it is bounded independent of $n$.

Thus, we have that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n
&=\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(b_n-b_\infty)}_{\text{converges by Dirichlet's Test}}+\underbrace{b_\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n}_{\substack{\text{constant multiple of}\\\text{a convergent series}}}
\end{align}
$$
converges.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering is this question has to be solved with Dirichlet's Test? I haven't learned it yet and have been assigned this question.

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen: You could use [partial summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula), in which case, you would essentially be reproving Dirichlet.

Answer (score 7):

While the proper way to prove the convergence of $\sum a_{n}b_{n}$ is the one provided by robjohn's answer, I would like to point out flaw in your argument. You start off correctly but you need to use the absolute values. Thus if $|b_{n}| \leq M$ for all $n$ and $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose a positive integer $n_{1}$ such that for all integers $m > n \geq n_{1}$ we have $$\left|\sum_{k = n}^{m}a_{k}\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{M}\tag{1}$$ Note that **this is not the same thing as** saying $$\sum_{k = n}^{m}|a_{k}| < \frac{\epsilon}{M}\tag{2}$$ Equation $(2)$ implies equation $(1)$ but $(1)$ **does not imply** $(2)$ because of the standard *triangle inequality* $$\left|\sum_{k = n}^{m}a_{k}\right| \leq \sum_{k = n}^{m}|a_{k}|\tag{3}$$ Now we can see that $$\left|\sum_{k = n}^{m}a_{k}b_{k}\right| \leq \sum_{k = n}^{m}|a_{k}b_{k}| \leq M\sum_{k = n}^{m}|a_{k}|$$ and your argument would work if equation $(2)$ holds. But unfortunately the equation $(1)$ holds instead of the much needed equation $(2)$ and therefore your argument is flawed and does not lead to a correct proof.